# IPs that cannot be used

Tags: ip, ip-address

I'm new to networking. I know that some IPs cannot be used and we cannot consider them when dedicating an IP. I know some of them such as:

```
Net ID Addresses
Loopback IP Addresses
Broadcast IP Addresses
```

Is there any other types of IPs that cannot be used?

Comment: You cannot use public IP addresses you don't own or got from your ISP.

Comment: @Zac67 I Know. I'm talking about the special group of the IPs that cannot be used in IP dedication in general.

Comment: Broadcast addresses can be used for broadcasts, and loopback addresses can be used internally to a host.

Comment: In *general*, 0/8 127/8 and 224/3 (multicast and reserved class E.) Unless you are creating a network, you shouldn't have to care; use an address valid for the network to which you are connecting. (in many cases, dhcp will do it for you.)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two IPs. IP stands for Internet Protocol, and there is IPv4 and IPv6. I think you mean IP addresses, not IPs.

It depends on what you mean by cannot be used.

There are ranges of IP addresses that cannot be used on the public Internet.

There are some addresses that cannot be used as a source address, some that cannot be used as a destination address, some that can only be used on a local link, etc.

Even the addresses in the loopback block can be used internally to a host.

Multicast addresses can only be used for multicast. Broadcast addresses can be used to broadcast (IPv6 does not have broadcast). There is one range that is RESERVED and should not be used at all, except for the Limited Broadcast address.

We have the *[IANA IPv4 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml)* and the *[IANA IPv6 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv6-special-registry/iana-ipv6-special-registry.xhtml)*, both of which list blocks of addresses with features showing if they can be used as source or destination addresses, are fowardable or globally reachable, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I'm talking about IPv4. When I want to config the IP on my laptop for example, I wanted to know which IP addresses can not be used in this case...

Comment: Again, that depends. For example, you can configure a link-local address if it is only going to need to communicate on the link, but that will not work if the packets need to be routed. IPv6 does not have the concept of broadcast, so the subnet and last address in the subnet (broadcast for IPv4) can be used as host addresses. Basically, if an address cannot be used as a source or destination address, then configuring that on an interface is foolish. Beyond that, it depends on what you want to use the address for. See the links in my answer.